# Should I use the formal form (~ます) on the buttons of an app?

Tags: translation, verbs, formality

I'm an iOS app developer who's learning Japanese. I want to localize my app to Japanese (make a Japanese version of it, basically). For context, my app falls into the "Utilities" category on the app store.

In the user interface of my app, suppose there is a button that says "Save". I want to replace the "Save" text with a Japanese translation. I thought of three ways to do this:

1. 保存
2. 保存する
3. 保存します

I'm wondering which one of those I should use. The first one is not a verb since it doesn't have the する at the end. So I guess it doesn't really imply that the button does a "save" action? Does this sound like, in English, when there is a button that applies some settings, instead of "Apply", it says "Application"? I think this is not appropriate, is it?

The second one sounds fine, but is it ok to use the plain form here? Is it too informal to be in a Utility app? Should I use the third instead?

I have seen other apps use the first and second form, like 完了 (the "Done" button) and 投稿する (I saw this in the Facebook app's "post" button). But since Facebook is a Social app, I guess it is ok to use the plain form because it sounds like Facebook is treating you like a close friend.

Which one should I use and why?

Comment: As others pointed out, your best strategy is to switch the language of your iOS device to Japanese, launch popular apps and see what they do. But yes, use 保存 for a button label and 保存しますか？etc. for a dialog. Also note that **system** bar button items (Save, Cancel, etc.) are automatically translated by the system.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm actually a developer working for a Japanese programming company.
It might depend on some people, but as far as buttons go.

> 「保存」、「登録」、「完了」、「キャンセル」

etc. seems like the way to go. Of course your will probably need a confirmation box in which you will usually write in the ます form.

> 「削除します。よろしいですか？」

It might be more common to write a verb on the button for less obvious/common actions like 「投稿する」

Also, I would probably not use the ます form on a button. If you feel like you have to, する probably seems more natural. It doesn't feel like you have to be polite with a button, it feels like the text on a button is what the client say to you, and not what you say to the client, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 11):

Please check Microsoft's [Japanese Style Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/3/4/b34f7185-afca-4846-8fbf-672a1b9afce2/jpn-jpn-StyleGuide.pdf) (for UI), in particular the Style section on Page 46.

> **Style**
>
> Use Desu-masu (ですます調, polite style), Dearu (である調, plain style)
> and noun phrase (体言止め) appropriately.
>
> When to use Desu-masu: In
> general, sentences should be translated in Desu-masu unless otherwise
> instructed. When the sentence prompts users to take an action, use
> “...してください。”. Example: Explanatory texts in windows, dialog boxes,
> message boxes and status bar (in software); Explanatory text except
> for headings (in document)
>
> When to use Dearu: When sentences should be briefly and simply
> translated, use Dearu. Noun phrase can be used depending on the
> situation (lack of space, etc.). Make sure to keep consistency on
> levels. Example: Check box, Option button (in software); Explanatory
> texts used as headings (in document)
>
> When to use noun phrase: When
> sentences should be briefly and simply translated, use noun phrase.
> Dearu and appropriate postpositional particles can be used depending
> on the situation. Make sure to keep consistency on levels. Example:
> Titles of menus and boxes, menu commands, labels in dialog boxes,
> command buttons, tabs, list items in list boxes or combo boxes (in
> software); Titles of web pages, headings, call-outs, captions (in
> documents)
> When using noun phrase, make sure to keep the expression simple and clear.
>
> Example:
>
> Show changes
> (+) 変更箇所の表示
> (-) 変更箇所を表示
>
> Open an item
> (+) アイテムを開く
> (-) アイテムの開き
> Note: Use Dearu instead for clarity

Somewhat related: [Why do road signs have 止まれ, not 止まる, 止める or 止めて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13019/3295)

**Edit**: you can also look up translations of various terms in different contexts on the [Microsoft's Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx), e.g:

https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-us/Search.aspx?sString=save&langID=ja-jp

Answer (score 4):

(I have Programming experience) You should ***not*** use 保存します.

---

### Because

In general, Using 保存 or 保存する in Japan.
For example, Look at the picture. This is a Twitter(Android)'s window.

[image: Screen shot]

It is written 保存. ...and Look at next Picture.

[image: Screen Shot]

This is a Chrome(This is also android version)'s window. It is written (something)を保存.